# Play2.3 does not combine non-webjar javascript files into the main RequireJS uglified file

Tags: requirejs, playframework-2.3, sbt-web

After upgrade to Play 2.3, requirejs is able to bundle and unglify all paths into the one main file ONLY if the path's come from a webjar.

Ie. if the config section of my require loos like this

```
paths: {
    bacon: '../lib/baconjs/Bacon.min', // comes from "org.webjars" % "baconjs" % "0.7.2"
    'bacon.model': 'libs/bacon.model-0.1.6'
```

Then `Bacon.min.js` is correctly bundled into my `main.js` file but the `bacon.model` library is downloaded separately via a http call.

I have a bunch of javascript depedencies that are not yet "webjared" so I am trying to find and easy way around this instead of making webjars of all dependancies not provided by webjars.org

Comment: Do you know how to achieve it with vanilla rjs? Because in that case you can actually provide the entire configuration to it from your SBT build (we recently did this to make some special require stuff work as we wanted). The key buildProfile is your friend! (See the docs at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-rjs)

Comment: Can you paste your complete config? I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I have since moved on from the role in which this problem existed (ie. no access to the source any more).